# Implement tables get all records has multiple tag in Cassandra database

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax

In Cassandra database, I have videos and tags, and every video can have multiple tags.

With below structure I can get videos has one specific tag:

```
CREATE TABLE VIDEOS_BY_TAG (
   tag text,
   video_id uuid,
   added_date timestamp,
   primary key ((tag), added_date, video_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (added_date desc, video_id asc);
```

But how can i have videos have multiple specific tags? for example get videos have all three Horror, Romance and Funny tags in Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use an IN clause for your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM VIDEOS_BY_TAG
WHERE TAG IN ('HORROR', 'ROMANCE', 'FUNNY');
```

Each tag/clause could hit a different node, but all records returned for a specific TAG will come from a single node. This is perfectly fine for small amounts. Keep in mind you don't want to overwhelm the system with a query that uses an IN clause with, say, 50 tags, as this could cause some contention due to cross-node results.

Depending on how things are being done, if this is code, a better approach is to simply fire off multiple queries, one for each TAG. This would be better as each coordinator could run from the specific node that relates to the TAG provided. 
v.s. having a single coordinator hit multiple nodes due to the IN clause.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: thanks, but I have more than 50 tags, and I can't query for each tag, because for example I want videos has 3 specific tags, not only one of them, or two of them